# Speed increases when holding down a mouseclick on the titlebar

Tags: c#, outlook, backgroundworker, add-in

I am working on an e-mail application and creating e-mails in a background worker.

The Background worker loops through all the contacts,
Each time it creates an e-mail and sends it to outlook and sends a backgroundworker.Reportprogress to update a form with information on what e-mails have been sent.

This works quite flawless and the performance is ok.

However, when I am clicking and holding down on the form's title bar (by example if someone was to move the form) the speed of the e-mail creating increases to almost double the speed.

I have tried debugging where I am loosing speed and if the updating of the UI is involved in slowing it down, but even if I don't send out the progressreport or show the progressform, the speed remains the same.

I am quite clueless on what is causing this issue. Any ideas are welcome.

This is the doWork method of my backgroundworker

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    sentContacts = new List<Contact>();

    double delay = GlobalVariables.delayBetweenBatch;

    while (contactSentId < contacts.Count && !bw.CancellationPending)
    {
        if (lastSending < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(delay))
        {
            for (int innerCounter = 0; innerCounter < GlobalVariables.emailsPerBatch; innerCounter++)
            {
                if (contactSentId < contacts.Count && !bw.CancellationPending)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = createMailItem(contacts[contactSentId], Application, wordReader, false);
                    bool success = sendMail(contacts[contactSentId], mailItem);

                    bw.ReportProgress(contactSentId + 1, new ResultContact(success, contacts[contactSentId]));

                    sentContacts.Add(contacts[contactSentId]);

                    contactSentId++;
                }
            }
            lastSending = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a profiler to see where you're actually spending time in both cases. I'd guess it's the Outlook interop that ends up behaving weird (COM thread apartments can cause funky behaviour). You're not running any of this in parallel, are you? The translation from MTA to STA would kill the parallelism anyway (provided the Outlook COM runs in STA - I'm not sure about that).

Comment: Does the window lose focus if you don't click to keep it focused? Windows (in "desktop" rather than "server" performance mode) gives a boost to the application that owns the foreground window, so if the system was also busy with other things, and something else kept grabbing the foreground while this was happening, then that could explain things.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker actually only executes a handful of nanoseconds worth of code on the worker thread.  Outlook is an apartment-threaded COM server, its methods run on the UI thread instead of the worker thread.  The operating system gives the UI thread a priority boost when you start dragging the window around.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

It does seem the backgroundworker is working on the same process as outlook, the only advantage I have from keeping this setup is that it allows me to stop the process when it is runnning, which I couldn't do without the use of the backgroundworker.

Is there a way that I am overlooking to be able to stop the sending of, let's say, 200 e-mails after 10 emails if the users decides he made a mistake other than using a backgroundworker?

Answer (score 0):

your check on lastSending is the wrong way around, you want to check if time Now is greater than lastSending+delay, to ensure that you do not send nails more frequently than the delay period.